# Prove $T_k(G)$ is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is an abelian $p$-group. $T_k(G)=\{g \in G : o(g) \, \,|\, \, p^k \}$ for $k \ge 0$.

Prove that this is a subgroup.

---

For closed within multiplication, it is easy to see that $o(a)o(b)\,\, | \, \,(p^k)^2$ but I forgot how to show it is a factor of $p^k$.

I have no idea for the inverses part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k\in\Bbb{N}$, and note that $o(x)\mid p^k\ \Leftrightarrow\ x^{p^k}=e$. For all $x,y\in G$ you have
$$(x^{p^k}=e\ \wedge\ y^{p^k}=e)\qquad \Rightarrow\qquad (x\cdot y)^{p^k}=x^{p^k}\cdot y^{p^k}=e\cdot e=e,$$
so $T_k(G)$ is closed under multiplication. Also 
$$x^{p^k}=e\qquad \Rightarrow\qquad (x^{-1})^{p^k}=(x^{p^k})^{-1}=e^{-1}=e,$$
so $T_k(G)$ is closed under taking inverses. Obviously $e\in T_k(G)$, so $T_k(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$.